# ValueError: The view create.views.CheckoutView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

I am getting a ValueError that the class below didn't return any httpresponse when i try to redirect to a template. the redirect is supposed to go to the stripe payment view.

here is an entire class that has the redirect call

```
class CheckoutView(View):
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    form = forms.CheckoutForm()
    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    return render(self.request, "checkout.html", context)

def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
    form = forms.CheckoutForm(self.request.POST or None)
    try:
        equipment_order = models.EquipmentOrder.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
        if form.is_valid():
            street_address = form.cleaned_data.get('street_address')
            apartment_address = form.cleaned_data.get('apartment_address')
            country = form.cleaned_data.get('country')
            zip = form.cleaned_data.get('zip')
            '''
            TODO: add functionality to these fields
            same_shipping_address = form.cleaned_data.get('same_shipping_address')
            save_info = form.cleaned_data.get('save_info')
            '''
            payment_option = form.cleaned_data.get('payment_option')
            billing_address = models.BillingAddress(
                user=self.request.user,
                street_address=street_address,
                apartment_address=apartment_address,
                country=country,
                zip=zip
            )
            billing_address.save()
            equipment_order.billing_address = billing_address
            equipment_order.save()

            if payment_option == 'S':                
                return redirect('create:payment', payment_option='stripe')
            elif payment_option == 'P':
                return redirect('create:payment', payment_option='paypal')
            else:
                messages.warning(self.request, "Invalid payment option")
                return redirect('create:checkout')
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        messages.error(self.request, "You do not have an active order")
        return redirect("create:order_summary")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Remove the try/except i think its better

2) I think you have a problem on 'payement_option' , maybe it doesnt give any value of expected , try to print it first to see what does it give

3) remove the ' or None ' from CheckoutForm

4) you can avoid using 'self' by importing form in that way :

```
from .forms import CheckoutForm
...
form = CheckoutForm(request.POST)
```

Comment: I tried everything but none worked. i then tried to print out what payment_option is giving and its doing what its suppose to do. i am really frustrated right now.

Comment: i can recommand you something , why dont do you use the complete words on the form like ( Paypal , Stripe ... ) , then you can just check if the value is not None :
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                
if payment_option is not None ;
                return redirect('create:payment', payment_option)
else :
                messages.warning(self.request, "Invalid payment option")
                return redirect('create:checkout')

Comment: You can also try using 'render' instead of 'redirect' , maybe it could cause the problem @Ivoredafe

Comment: render did not work and its a a tuple of a tuple s is stripe and p is paypal so i cant change it

Comment: can u try HttpResponse and see if it works ? @Ivoredafe

Answer (score 0):

The above answer may work fine but as I tried your code it throws the same error as you described whenever you leave the form field empty or no payment method is selected.

After trying your code the best possible solution I figure out is this. I know this is not a perfect solution but it worked

Suggestion: Try to move your else statement under if instead of nesting it after elif statement. And change your else to given below.

Old:

```
    else:
       messages.warning(self.request, "Invalid payment option select")
       return redirect('core:checkout')
```

New:

```
    else :
        messages = 'Invalid payment option select'
        return HttpResponse(messages)
```

Proof: [Invalid payment option select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPiZG.png)